# Xamarin IOS Binding Library DLL Not Found

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am new xamarin forms i want to integrate [freshChat](https://support.freshchat.com/support/solutions/articles/232945-freshchat-ios-sdk-integration) in xamarin forms so i added IOS binding library and added ApiDefinition, LibFDFreshChatSDK.a & Struct

I Add Reference of IOS Binding Library to Xamarin IOS Project but Dll is found in Xamarin IOS Debug folder but not able to access the Classes & NameSpace

I Copy the Dll from IOS Binding Library and Added To New Folder and provide a reference to it then i Can Access the Classes & Namespace but it show the error of

1. Native linking failed. Please review the build log
2. Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioSession SetActive With Flags
3. Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _AudioSessionSetProperty

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar issue, did you managed to solve it?